# use `exivtool` to rename Photos by location

Tags: exif

This is how you can rename all Jpegs in a folder by geolocation and date:

```
exiftool '-filename<${gpslatitude;} ${gpslongitude} ${datetimeoriginal}' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S%%-c.%%e" *.JPG
```

this results in very long filenames like

```
53 33 36.95000000 N 9 58 29.37000000 E 2015-11-04 19.22.49.JPG
```

How can I use the short locations instead? So it would result in

```
53.560308 9.975458 2015-11-04 19.22.49.JPG
```

Or even better, Is it possible to get and add the City of the geolocation and add it to the name?

Comment: See option `-coordFormat` in `man exiftool`: e.g. `-coordFormat "%.6f"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will result in a shorter version:

```
exiftool -coordFormat '%.4f' '-filename<${gpslatitude;} ${gpslongitude} ${datetimeoriginal}_$filename' -d "%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S%%-c.%%e" *.JPG
```

But it still adds the compass point N,E,S or W

If you want to add the city, this could be added with a loop, using the [nominatim API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#exiftool '-filename<${datetimeoriginal}_$filename' -d "%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S%%-c.%%e" *.JPG
for f in *.JPG; do
  echo "$f"
  LAT="$(exiftool -coordFormat '%.4f' "$f"|egrep 'Latitude\s+:'|cut -d\  -f 23)"
  if [ "$LAT" == "" ]; then 
    echo 'no geo coordinates';
  else
    LON="$(exiftool -coordFormat '%.4f' "$f"|egrep 'Longitude\s+:'|cut -d\  -f 22)"
    URL='http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat='$LAT'&lon='$LON'&zoom=18&addressdetails=1'
    RES="$(curl -s "$URL"|egrep "<(city|village|town|ruins|state_district|country)")"
    LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<city>'|sed 's/^.*<city>//g'|sed 's/<\/city>.*$//g')"
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then 
      LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<city_district>'|sed 's/^.*<city_district>//g'|sed 's/<\/city_district>.*$//g')"
    fi
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then 
      LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<village>'|sed 's/^.*<village>//g'|sed 's/<\/village>.*$//g')"
    fi
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then 
      LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<town>'|sed 's/^.*<town>//g'|sed 's/<\/town>.*$//g')"
    fi
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then 
      LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<ruins>'|sed 's/^.*<ruins>//g'|sed 's/<\/ruins>.*$//g')"
    fi
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then 
      LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<state_district>'|sed 's/^.*<state_district>//g'|sed 's/<\/state_district>.*$//g')"
    fi
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then 
      LOC="$(echo "$RES"|grep '<country>'|sed 's/^.*<country>//g'|sed 's/<\/country>.*$//g')"
    fi
    if [ "$LOC" == "" ]; then
      echo "no city found at $URL";
    else 
      BASE="${f%.*}"
      mv -v "$f" "$BASE-$LOC.JPG"
    fi
  fi
done
```

When you are done, you can count your images by location with

```
ls -1|cut -d- -f 4|sort|uniq -c|sort -n
```

Comment: The exiftool manpage says: `If the hemisphere is known, a reference direction (N, S, E or W) is appended to each printed coordinate, but adding a "+" to the format specifier (eg. "%+.6f") prints a signed coordinate instead`

Comment: Instead of Google maps you may also use the [Nominatim API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) from the OpenStreetMap Project

Comment: @ridgy: thanks, I added a solution with Nominatim